# How is /dev/zero created and how can I make variants like /dev/one?

Tags: linux, drivers, unix

I read the `mknod` man page, which is (as far as I can tell) what you would use to make a character device like `/dev/zero`, but I don't see how you would get it to yield an infinite stream of zero bits (or another pattern). What is the procedure for creating such character devices?

Comment: They're implemented in the kernel. Look at `zero_lseek`, `read_zero`, `write_zero`, `mmap_zero` in `drivers/char/mem.c`.

Comment: Oh…so I would have to modify the kernel?

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends on precisely what you want to do. Most likely, you would at least need to implement a module.

Comment: What about `/dev/one`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All `mknod` does is associate a device file with a device driver. There are device drivers that implement interaction with actual devices, and there are device drivers that just react to read-write requests in useful ways.  If you want to you can sit down and write a driver that returns the lyrics of the [Star Spangeled Banner](http://youtu.be/xus1YlW_PQU). But it's a matter of coding, not finding the right arguments for `mknod`.

Answer (score 4):

`mknod` creates the device node, but the VFS detects accesses to the device node and reroutes them to the appropriate driver within the kernel for handling. All device nodes, from `/dev/null` to `/dev/sdX` to `/dev/ttyXX` to `/dev/videoX` are handled this way.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to re-create the `/dev/zero` abilities but with a character other than zero/null, you can use `tr` to change all the zero's ("\000" in octal) into something else.

So to spit out an endless stream of "a"s for example, you could do:

```
cat /dev/zero | tr "\000" "\141" | head -c 20
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Or skip the cat and output an M's worth (1024*1024) with

```
head -c 1M /dev/zero |tr "\000" "\141"
```

"\141" being the "a" character.

See this site http://www.asciitable.com/ for a quick short page of ASCII - Octal codes. It's actually this image here:
[image]

(I know, old "solved" question, but I found it while searching for an endless stream of different characters, so this "solves" the "how to make /dev/one or /dev/[different character]" problem.)

Comment: I dunno…based on unscientific I-just-tried-it-right-now, `head | tr >file` has varying degrees of overhead. Depending on the system, it takes either one, one and a half, or two times as long as just `head >file`.

Comment: So it does, tr's a workhorse I guess. Trying `head -c 3G ... > /dev/null` took under a second, but adding the pipe to `tr` took 21 seconds. Still about 150mb/sec so probably faster than most hard drives could keep up to. But it works, and there is no built-in /dev/one or /dev/a, etc

Comment: Hence my asking after one!